# How to use Proxy All in WireMock Cloud?

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

The Local Standalone JAR has an option of `--proxy-all`, but I am looking for the equivalent in the WireMock Cloud service. I want any paths that I haven't mocked to be proxied to the base URL of the live or production environment. Can someone advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that proxying with WireMock Cloud is done "per-stub" as their documentation explains: https://docs.wiremock.io/proxying/

It seems that proxying *all* mappings with one setting isn't a feature they support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on WireMock Web UI -

- Create a new endpoint with `/.*` [this acts as a catch-all]
- Set the URL type as 'path and query regex'
- Assign the lowest priority to this rule (e.g., 10) [only gets used when no other stub matches]
- Set your live/prod URL as the base URL